# Meaning "llegar sobre la (time)"

Tags: expresiones, preposiciones, tiempo

What's the meaning of this?

> Llego sobre las 3

It means before, around, after, after but not by much?

Comment: Is it exactly _llego_ or _llegó_?

Comment: Also: where did you hear it? What country was the speaker from? Some context would help

Answer (score 4):

The expression:

- *llegar sobre la hora*

or

- *llegar sobre X hora (las 2, las 3, las 4)*

means "arriving just in time", with absolutely no time or very little time left. The implication is that the arrival was close to being a late arrival, and the person (or a delivery, or a form of transportation) narrowly avoided it.

This use seems to be common in several Latin American countries:

- Mexico: El impresionante gol de Funes Mori sobre la hora en la final entre Monterrey y América de México ([Source](https://www.minutouno.com/notas/5073423-el-impresionante-gol-funes-mori-la-hora-la-final-monterrey-y-america-mexico))
- Argentina: Liverpool ganó sobre la hora ([Source](https://www.lacapitalmdp.com/liverpool-gano-sobre-la-hora/))
- Uruguay: [...] sobre la hora optó por vestir la camiseta del “Rayadito” ([Source](https://www.versus.com.py/2019/12/27/le-volvieron-a-dormir-al-kelito/))
- Chile: Leeds de Marcelo Bielsa igualó sobre la hora ante Preston y sigue sublíder de la Championship ([Source](https://www.biobiochile.cl/noticias/futbol-internacional/notas-futbol-internacional/2019/12/26/leeds-de-marcelo-bielsa-igualo-sobre-la-hora-ante-preston-y-sigue-sublider-de-la-championship.shtml))

Comment: I don't fully agree. If someone tells me _Llego sobre las 3_, I assume they will be arriving around 3, on a range of 10? 20? mins. Otherwise, in Spain, people would say _llegaré a las 3 clavadas_ or similar. But it may be different depending on the country

Comment: @fedorqui In my country, "sobre" is used to express what I explained in my reply. For example, it is very usual to hear things like *El equipo metió un gol sobre el final*.

Comment: Ah right, then I may post an answer with the Spanish from Soain approach

Comment: @Gustavson. From your profile I see "your country" is Argentina. That is highly relevant information. I agree with fedorqui about the usage in Spain. There are of course different uses throughout the world, but knowing how you speak in "your country" is not of much use if you don't say which country that is.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt It seems to be the case not only in "my country".

Comment: @Gustavson where, then? Cono sur? All of south america? All of latin america? I lived in Spain for 6 years. I also spent some time working with Colombians (3 months in Colombia and a year over the phone from Scotland.) I don't remember the use of "sobre" causing any misunderstandings, but it may simply never have come up.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I assumed you had read what I added to my reply.

Comment: This answer is valid for Mexico. I'd go farther, in fact.  In practice in Mexico it means *punctually* [at a certain time]. But @fedorqui - I think it's a great idea to post another answer, to show the regional difference.

Comment: So "llegar sobre las 3" would mean "to arrive right before 3" in Latin America?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In Spain, someone saying *Llego sobre las 3* sounds as a message being sent when somebody is notifying another about the approximate time they will be arriving.

If I heard this, I would assume that they will arrive somewhere between 2.45 and 3.15, that is, at 3 with some delay or advance.

Other options can be:

- Llego a eso de las 3
- Llegaré hacia las 3

If that person would want to specify they will be exactly on time, they would say either of these:

- Llego a las 3 clavadas
- Llego a las 3 en punto

Comment: So "llego sobre las 3" in Spain could be translated to English as "I'm going to arrive around 3".

Comment: @Alan exactly!!